# Pandas: Apply transformations to all character columns

Tags: python, r, pandas

I am working in Python to try and apply a few transformations to all character/string columns in a pandas dataframe. The transformations are:

- Make everything uppercase
- Trim the white space

I come from an R background and this can be achieved via something like

```
mydf <- mydf %>% 
  dplyr::mutate_if(is.character, toupper)
  dplyr::mutate_if(is.character, trimws)
```

For Python I am at a loss. I have tried the below where it first identifies all the character columns and then attempts to trim the whitespace and make all the character columns upper case (Species in this case)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris

# Create a sample dataset
iris = load_iris()

df= pd.DataFrame(data= np.c_[iris['data'], iris['target']],
                 columns= iris['feature_names'] + ['target'])

df['species'] = pd.Categorical.from_codes(iris.target, iris.target_names)

# Make character columns upper case and then trim the white space
string_dtypes = df.convert_dtypes().select_dtypes("string")
df[string_dtypes.columns] = string_dtypes.apply(lambda x: x.str.upper())
df[string_dtypes.columns] = string_dtypes.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip())

df
```

I appreciate this might be a very basic question and thank you in advance to anyone who takes the time to help

Comment: What's the problem with your code?

Comment: Hi @Ynjxsjmh, nothing changed in the dataframe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to do this in one line with method chaining:

```py
df.astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.str.upper().str.strip())
```

Output:

```
    sepal length (cm)   sepal width (cm)    petal length (cm)   petal width (cm)    target  species
0   5.1 3.5 1.4 0.2 0.0 SETOSA
1   4.9 3.0 1.4 0.2 0.0 SETOSA
2   4.7 3.2 1.3 0.2 0.0 SETOSA
3   4.6 3.1 1.5 0.2 0.0 SETOSA
4   5.0 3.6 1.4 0.2 0.0 SETOSA
... ... ... ... ... ... ...
145 6.7 3.0 5.2 2.3 2.0 VIRGINICA
146 6.3 2.5 5.0 1.9 2.0 VIRGINICA
147 6.5 3.0 5.2 2.0 2.0 VIRGINICA
148 6.2 3.4 5.4 2.3 2.0 VIRGINICA
149 5.9 3.0 5.1 1.8 2.0 VIRGINICA
```

Comment: Hi @SamR, this is exactly what i was after and is far more elegant. Thank you very much. I have to wait for five mins before it will allow me to accept the answer